# Facebook Share Popup-Button Stops to Work after First Click

Tags: javascript, facebook, popup, share

I have a Facebook Button on my page. It calls a share popup.

The problem is that button works just on the first click. The second, third clicks don't do nothing. I always need to refresh the page.

I'm a newbie. Could you help me with this code?

Thank you.

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'zzzzzzzzzz', 
          status     : true, 
          cookie     : true,
          xfbml      : true  
        });

        FB.ui(
          {
            method: 'feed',
            name: 'Bitcoin Catcher Faucet & Rotator', 
            link: 'http://bitcoin-catcher.com',
            picture: 'http://bitcoin-catcher.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/icon.png',
            caption: 'Only 1000+ Rewards Faucet & Rotator', 
            description: 'Earn FREE Bitcoins Easier & Faster! Only 1000+ Rewards per Claim!' 
          },  

          function(response) {
            if (response && response.post_id) {
    unhide('claim', '');
            } else {
            }
          }
        );

      };

     function fb_callout() {

      (function(d){
             var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
             if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
             js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
             ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
             }(document));
         }
    </script> 

<img alt="Share on Facebook" src="http://bitcoin-catcher.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/facebook-share-button.png" width="180" onclick="fb_callout();" style="cursor: pointer;" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The call to `FB.ui` should be outside `fbAsyncInit`. Place it in the click event handler of the Share button.

In your code sample, the FB JS SDK is **loaded with every click**. *This is not what you want.*

Even though it works the first time because the SDK calls fbAsyncInit once it's loaded which in turn - in your example, mistakenly again - displays the feed dialog through an FB.ui call, reloading the SDK breaks the API for subsequent calls. **The SDK should not be loaded every time.**

What you want instead is to load the SDK only once when the page loads (it's asynchronous so it wont block the browser) and then assign a click handler to the button which calls FB.ui.

It'd look something similar to the below

```
<body>
<img alt="Share on Facebook" onclick="fb_callout();" />

<script>
  // Handler for click event
  function fb_callout() {
    FB.ui({...}, function(response) {});
  }

  // This is called when the SDK js file is loaded by the browser
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'zzzzzzzzzz', 
      status     : true, 
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true  
    });
  }

  // This loads the FB SDK js
  (function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Marekful. I did change the code this way and it didn' work. This time the first click stopped to work too. Could you put an example of code?

Comment: Just do it as in my answer. Look at it carefully. You still put everything in fb_callout function ;)

Comment: Thank you. Now the popup opens at every click. But now is happening other problem. I can't login into facebook through the popup on Chrome. The Chrome popup just show a white page when a send my -mail and password. At Firefox the problem is similar, THe popup open saying "Error. Try again later". :(

Comment: I did solve the problem. I needed to replicate the `function(d)` inside the `fb_callout` function (after the `FB.ui` code). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I did this way and nothing happens...

```
<img alt="Share on Facebook" src="http://bitcoin-catcher.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/facebook-share-button.png" width="180" onclick="fb_callout();" style="cursor: pointer;" />

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>

function fb_callout() {

    FB.ui(
      {
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'Bitcoin Catcher Faucet & Rotator', 
        link: 'http://bitcoin-catcher.com',
        picture: 'http://bitcoin-catcher.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/icon.png',
        caption: 'Only 1000+ Rewards Faucet & Rotator', 
        description: 'Earn FREE Bitcoins Easier & Faster! Only 1000+ Rewards per Claim!' 
      },  

      function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
unhide('claim', '');
        } else {
        }
      }
    );

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxx', 
      status     : true, 
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true  
    });

  (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
         }(document));
     }

  };


</script>
```